# Azure Synapse : What should I do so that I can access the Power BI report on Power BI service without having to enable the "Public Network Access"?

Tags: sql-server, azure, powerbi, azure-synapse

I have an Azure Synapse Workspace with SQL Server Dedicated Pool

[image]

and have Disabled the Public Network Access

[image]

and loaded data

[image]

I could fetch the data

[image]

and I have loaded the data into Power BI desktop application

[image]

and I have used "Direct Query"

[image]

I have published the Power BI Report from the VM

[image]

However, I am not able to open the Report or Dataset in Power BI Service

> Failed to update data source credentials: Reason: An instance-specific
> error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
> Connection was denied since Deny Public Network Access is set to Yes
> (https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-settings#deny-public-network-access).
> To connect to this server, use the Private Endpoint from inside your
> virtual network
> (https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/sql-database/sql-database-private-endpoint-overview#how-to-set-up-private-link-for-azure-sql-database).

as well as report is not loading in Azure Synapse

[image]

> What should I do so that I can access the Power BI report on the Power BI service as well as on the Azure Synapse Studio without having to enable the "Public Network Access"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your Synapse Warehouse have a private endpoint? (Assuming yes) There are two ways of approaching this. You can deploy a VM in the same VNet where you can install the on-premises data gateway, you might have to add some NSG rules for connectivity to fully work if it's a locked down VNet.

Alternatively, you can try VNet integration which lets you communicate with the Power BI service privately without the need of setting up the on-premises data gateway. That feature is in preview, however.

Then when your datasets are published, you just set the datasources to use your newly deployed gateway.

Comment: I have setup the required private endpoints like studio, sql, sql on-demand & etc. I have deployed the VM in the same VNET as Synapse. Can you please help me with the steps or articles that explain the VNet integration which lets you communicate with the Power BI service privately?

Comment: I found this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/vnet/create-data-gateways. However, what do we use in general, VNET data gateway or on-premises data gateway?

Comment: This article may also help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/vnet/use-data-gateways-sources-power-bi. In terms of which to use, if this will become a production workload, I would use the VM with On-Premises Data Gateway given the preview nature of the VNet Integration Gateway

Comment: Thank you, @johubb. I followed this article https://www.datahai.co.uk/power-bi/connecting-power-bi-to-azure-sql-database-using-private-endpoints/

Comment: No problem, Andy Cutler's articles are great